# Should I synchronize autowired DAO spring bean in the controller?

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc app. It's simple SMS app. I receive an SMS then I should return the back SMS. I have simple DAO class where are all of my queries to one table. SMS-es are received sequentially but one answer could overtake another dependent of the processing time needed. I autowire my DAO in my controller. The question is should I synchronize the calls to my DAO which is field in my controller class and its visible from all the requests. If the requests are sequential and do not overlap I think its not needed but if one request processing time takes longer than several sms-es received right after the longer one its needed I think. Am i right ?

EDIT:

here is simple method in my DAO which is not synchronized:

```
public boolean isDatetimesAlreadyRegisteredForMSISDN(String msisdn, LocalDate date, LocalTime time){
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select p from Participants p where p.msisdn = :msisdn and p.date = :date and p.time = :time");
        query.setParameter("msisdn", msisdn);
        query.setParameter("date", date);
        query.setParameter("time", time);
        return !query.getResultList().isEmpty();
    }
```

entityManager is a field which is hibernate persistence context and I thing its thread-safe.

Comment: It all depends on the code of your DAO. If it's thread-safe, you don't need to synchronize anything. If it's not, synchronization is needed... where it's needed. DAOs are usually stateless, and thus thread-safe. Synchronization is needed when mutable state is accessed concurrently. That's probably not the case of your DAO. But without seeing any code...

Comment: I put simple dao method in my question. So I just have to make my dao methods synchronized and all is ok now ?

Comment: No, absolutely not. Read my comment again. You don't need any synchronization at all. This would force all calls to be executed sequentially, for no reason at all, since they can safely be executed concurrently, and thus let you smaller response time and better throughput. Your DAO is thread-safe as it is.

Comment: I understood thanks

Comment: you don't do  any synchronization. but , take into acount that hibernate session connected with transaction . transaction isolation  it's 'synchronization '  in db level see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)